# Invalid list count in setting breakpoint outside of Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I understand that when using TPL Parallel.ForEach, we do not need to explicitly write code to "wait" for the tasks inside it to complete. However, I am doing a simple transfer of 1000 elements from a source list into a destination list. On setting a breakpoint OUTSIDE and AFTER the Parallel.ForEach loop, I see an invalid/incomplete count of the items in the destination list... Why?

```
List<int> myList = new List<int> { };
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    myList.Add(i);
}
List<int> newList = new List<int>();
Parallel.ForEach(myList, x => {
    newList.Add(x);
});
Thread.Sleep(5000);
var test = newList.Count;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` isn't thread-safe so you can't use that in parallel code. You should use [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) (or any other thread-safe collection) instead:

```
var bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
Parallel.ForEach(myList, x =>
{
    bag.Add(x);
});
```

You could also use a `lock` around the `newList` but that would make the parallelization useless.

Comment: Well, this parallelization most likely is useless, even if you use `ConcurrentBag` to avoid the lock.